# Android - Import database get nullpointerexception on rawquery

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.char95.com/importing-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to import database. Then I try to read the data using ArrayList to display them in listview. But I got nullpointer exception on my rawQuery saying it is invoking a null object reference.

DB.java

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH           = "data/data/hairulhazri.malayforyou/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME           = "malayforyou";
private static String TABLE_LOCATION    = "Frasa";

private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


// constructor
public DB(Context context) {

    super( context , DB_NAME , null , 1);
    this.context = context;

}


// Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
public void create() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

// Check if the database exist to avoid re-copy the data
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        // database don't exist yet.
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

// copy your assets db to the new system DB
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

//Open the database
public boolean open() {

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return true;

    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        db = null;
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(db != null)
        db.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// PUBLIC METHODS TO ACCESS DB CONTENT
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


public ArrayList<Frasa> getFrasa(String situation) {

    //ArrayList of Frasa class objects
    ArrayList<Frasa> arrFrasa = null;
    //String query = "SELECT * FROM Frasa WHERE Situation = " + situation;

    String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
            Frasa.KEY_ID + "," +
            Frasa.KEY_PHRASE + "," +
            Frasa.KEY_TRANSLATE + "," +
            Frasa.KEY_PRONOUNCE +
            " FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION + " WHERE situation = " +situation;


    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( DB_PATH + DB_NAME , null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    Cursor curFrasa = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (curFrasa != null && curFrasa.moveToFirst()) {
        arrFrasa = new ArrayList<Frasa>();
        while (curFrasa.isAfterLast() == false) {
            //Frasa is a class with list of fields
            Frasa fra = new Frasa();
            fra.setId(curFrasa.getInt(curFrasa.getColumnIndex(Frasa.KEY_ID)));
            fra.setPhrase(curFrasa.getString(curFrasa.getColumnIndex(Frasa.KEY_PHRASE)));
            fra.setTranslate(curFrasa.getString(curFrasa.getColumnIndex(Frasa.KEY_TRANSLATE)));
            fra.setPronounce(curFrasa.getString(curFrasa.getColumnIndex(Frasa.KEY_PRONOUNCE)));
            arrFrasa.add(fra);
            curFrasa.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    curFrasa.close();
    db.close();
    return arrFrasa;
  }
}
```

Frasa.java (Database table and columns)

```
public class Frasa {



// Labels Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_PHRASE = "phrase";
public static final String KEY_TRANSLATE = "translate";
public static final String KEY_PRONOUNCE = "pronounce";


// property help us to keep data
public int id;
public String situation;
public String phrase;
public String translate;
public String pronounce;


public Frasa() {
}

public Frasa(int id, String situation, String phrase, String translate, String pronounce) {
    this.id = id;
    this.situation = situation;
    this.phrase = phrase;
    this.translate = translate;
    this.pronounce = pronounce;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPhrase() {
    return phrase;
}

public void setPhrase(String phrase) {
    this.phrase = phrase;
}

public String getTranslate() {
    return translate;
}

public void setTranslate(String translate) {
    this.translate = translate;
}

public String getPronounce() {
    return pronounce;
}

public void setPronounce(String pronounce) {
    this.pronounce = pronounce;
}
}



public class GreetingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Frasa> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Frasa> data = new ArrayList<Frasa>();

public GreetingAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Frasa> data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.textPhrase = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhrase);
        holder.textTranslate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewTranslate);
        holder.btnSpeak = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonSpeak);
        holder.btnRecord = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
        holder.btnPlay = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Frasa frasa = data.get(position);
    holder.textPhrase.setText(frasa.getPhrase());
    holder.textTranslate.setText(frasa.getTranslate());
    holder.btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Speak button Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    holder.btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete button Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    holder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Play Button Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Playing recorded audio",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return row;

}

static class UserHolder {
    TextView textPhrase;
    TextView textTranslate;
    Button btnSpeak;
    Button btnRecord;
    Button btnPlay;
}
}
```

activity_list_greetings.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Greetings"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listGreetings"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_header" />
```

list_item_greet.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPhrase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Phrase"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonRecord"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSpeak"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Speak"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonRecord"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSpeak"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Record"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonRecord"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Play"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTranslate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Translate"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/background_material_dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonRecord"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ListGreetings.java

```
public class ListGreetings extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView txtPhrase, txtTranslate;
Button speakButton;
MediaPlayer pronounce;

ListView userList;
GreetingAdapter greetAdapter;

//ArrayList<Frasa> frasaArray = new ArrayList<Frasa>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_greetings);


    DB db = new DB(this);
    db.open();


    //get Frasa data
        ArrayList<Frasa> frasaArray = db.getFrasa("Greetings");


        /**
         * set item into adapter
         */
        greetAdapter = new GreetingAdapter(ListGreetings.this, R.layout.list_item_greet, frasaArray);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listGreetings);
        userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        userList.setAdapter(greetAdapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_greetings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Is it my way of calling `getFrasa` wrong? Or the database cannot be detected? I'm sure I already pushed the database file to both assets folder & inside the package. Sorry, if I'm not formatting the codes correctly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow! is very valuable show the error message displayed in LogCat, so easily we can find the problem :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. This is the error message........


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
            at hairulhazri.malayforyou.database.DB.getFrasa(DB.java:194)
            at hairulhazri.malayforyou.ListGreetings.onCreate(ListGreetings.java:42)

Comment: Inside ListGreetings.java oncreate() : 

ArrayList<Frasa> frasaArray = db.getFrasa("Greetings");

Comment: whats the complete name of your DB? "malayforyou.db" ???

Comment: It's just 'malayforyou'. File type 'File' but it can be opened in SQLite Browser.

Comment: probably thats the problem, your DB would be corrupt, a DB in SQlite format doesn´t have problem to be opened in SQL Browser :0

Comment: Read the tutorial: I recommend you to download SQLite Database Browser. Is opensource and available for Windows, Linux and Mac.
Create a new database named, for example, "AppDB". you must set the DB into the assets folder :P

Comment: I created this DB using SQLite Browser but somehow it cannot be saved as malayforyou.db. It is saved as malayforyou.sqbpro. Is that usable? How to save it to malayforyou.db?

Comment: What's weird is, I got a friend who's doing a project quiet similar to this. We're working on our final year project together. His DB is just like mine, with no .db extension but it can still run properly. So he was helping me to solve this problem all night but here I am posting codes here on 6 am. Haha sorry I just feel not really sane right now.

Comment: the extension isn´t important just put the database file inside your /assets folder.

Comment: It's already there.  src/main/assets/malayforyou. Is that directory correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to open the Database from a different location

```
private static String DB_PATH = "data/data/hairulhazri.malayforyou/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "malayforyou";
...
...
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( DB_PATH + DB_NAME , null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

`db` is returning `NULL` because your database is stored in `/assets` folder not in `"data/data/hairulhazri.malayforyou/databases/"`

Comment: I store the database in assets folder and I also pushed the database to the package in DDMS, just like in the tutorial.

Comment: I'm sorry @Elenasys but I don't really understand. What's the exact problem actually? You said the path is wrong but I did that because I followed the tutorial. It makes me confused.